# Optimal Approach to Unpivoting JSON Data Fields

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I'm working with a database to convert a column of stored raw JSON formatted data into a format with the following columns.

```
UserId | QuestionText | AnswerText | LoadDate
```

The JSON data follows a consistent structure, starting with a common set of shared fields before specific input forms are listed in an array.  Each record in the table contains one of these raw JSON strings.  Despite the input forms being listed as an array, only one (at most) will be picked for a single row in the table.  This data is stored in a SQL Server 2016 database, and some of the fields within the JSON data are objects or arrays themselves.  There could be any number of children of one of these objects or arrays that are objects or arrays themselves, and so on.

The JSON data is being returned using `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` or `OUTER APPLY OPENJSON` alongside the `WITH` keyword to specify the fields needed to be returned with appropriate data types.  All of the JSON querying is being done with `lax` rather than `strict`.

The resulting general query shell looks something like this.

```
SELECT
    formData.UserId,
    interests.Weekends,
    interests.Holidays,
    jdt.LoadDate
FROM
    dbo.JsonDataTable jdt
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jdt.JsonField, 'lax $')
WITH
(
    [Source] VARCHAR(15) '$."source"',
    [UserId] VARCHAR(25) '$."UserId"',
    [InterestsJson] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$."Interests"' AS JSON
) formData
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(formData.InterestsJson, 'lax $')
WITH
(
    [Weekends] VARCHAR(200) '$."weekends"',
    [Holidays] VARCHAR(200) '$."holidays"'
) interests
WHERE
    jdt.JsonField IS NOT NULL
    AND jdt.JsonField <> ''
    AND jdt.FormId = @FormId
    AND jdt.FormId = formData.source
    AND jdt.LoadDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

This pattern continues until all child arrays and objects are resolved into their respective fields, and each one of these OPENJSON joins will explode the result set by the number of records stored in each array/object.  Obviously, this adds a lot of overhead as the row count expands with each additional array added into the query.

Once this data is finalized, the result set is pushed into an `UNPIVOT` operation.

```
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    u.QuestionText,
    u.AnswerText,
    u.LoadDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        formData.UserId,
        interests.Weekends,
        interests.Holidays,
        jdt.LoadDate
    FROM
        dbo.JsonDataTable jdt
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jdt.JsonField, 'lax $')
    WITH
    (
        [Source] VARCHAR(15) '$."source"',
        [UserId] VARCHAR(25) '$."UserId"',
        [InterestsJson] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$."Interests"' AS JSON
    ) formData
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(formData.InterestsJson, 'lax $')
    WITH
    (
        [Weekends] VARCHAR(200) '$."weekends"',
        [Holidays] VARCHAR(200) '$."holidays"'
    ) interests
    WHERE
        jdt.JsonField IS NOT NULL
        AND jdt.JsonField <> ''
        AND jdt.FormId = @FormId
        AND jdt.FormId = formData.source
        AND jdt.LoadDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
) q
UNPIVOT
(
    AnswerText
    FOR QuestionText IN
    (
        Weekends,
        Holidays
    )
) u;
```

This appears to be extremely slow for processing large amounts of raw JSON data stored as a VARCHAR(MAX) field in a table.  The fields being filtered in the WHERE clause are all indexed, and the indexes are being hit as expected.  For one of the more highly used input forms it takes approximately 3 minutes to return 15 minutes of data.

**QUESTION**

Is there a better approach to this?  The data **must** be in this output format, and the input format **cannot** be changed from raw JSON strings dumped into a column that must be filtered for only the specific input form being requested.  The table's rows themselves cannot be filtered outside of the JSON string to only return a single input form's JSON data.  For whatever reason, this data was set up so each record is a total collection of everything submitted for that user instead of each input form's submission appearing as its own row.  I've estimated that to back-load the data for one of the larger input forms it will take in excess of 14 hours with this approach, and I need to back-load approximately 250 input forms.